# Decrypt a node.js aes-256-cbc string in openssl

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl

I have the following example code that generates an encrypted value in node.js using the `aes-256-cbc` algorithm, a fixed `key`, and an `iv` in node.js.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const iv = '0f9387b3f94bf06f';
const key = 'ZTk0YTU5YjNhMjk4NGI3NmIxNWExNzdi';

const encrypt = (value) => {
   const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('AES-256-CBC', key, iv);
   let encrypted = cipher.update(value, 'utf8', 'hex');
   encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
   return encrypted;
};

console.log('Encrypted value: ', encrypt('HelloWorld'));
```

The encrypted value that is created by the above script, encrypted the string `HelloWorld` is the following `hex` value:

`0c491f8c5256b9744550688fc54926e8`

In `bash` and using `openssl` what script can I execute with the given encrypted value above to give me a decrypted value of `HeloWorld`?

I have spent lots of time struggling on this, using `openssl`, various options and accompanying commands but am struggling to generate the same output.

Any gurus out there who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options), the function `crypto.createCipher()` doesn't use salt. You then need to explicitly say it to `openssl`.

Moreover the function you use doesn't expect IV. If you would require IV, then use `crypto.createCipheriv()`.

So the `openssl` command is the following:

```
$ echo dd64232d380669d1a09378e1dc9de762 | xxd -ps -r | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k ZTk0YTU5YjNhMjk4NGI3NmIxNWExNzdi -nosalt
HelloWorld
```

Note that I'm using `xxd` to convert the string into bytes. You could use `hexdump`, `od` or other...

---

In response of the last OP's change, here the correct `openssl` command.
Obviously if you specify explicitly the IV, you don't need the salt and need to the key in bytes format (option `-K`)

```
echo 0c491f8c5256b9744550688fc54926e8 | xxd -ps -r | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -iv 30663933383762336639346266303666 -K 5a546b3059545535596a4e684d6a6b344e4749334e6d49784e5745784e7a6469
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the original node sample and encrypted value I gave were incorrect, this is a fault of mine through trying to understand why decryption wasn't working.  The edited code sample is using `crypto.createCipheriv()`.

Comment: My mistake, as the original code sample was incorrect, now the code has been edited the answer you gave (although correctly for my incorrect sample) does not solve the problem.

Comment: Awesome, how did you convert the `-iv` and `-K` to the different byte format?